# Fill an Outlook email template using words from a Word document using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, email-templates

I am creating a Word document which contains macros that will convert the .doc to .PDF, and include it as an attachment in an autogenerated Outlook email containing the following body:

" Hello (name),

Thank you for contacting us. Please find the attached quotation for:
Scope of work: (Scope)"

I would like to replace (name) and (scope) with the customer name and the scope of work entered in the Word document

The information that will be filled by the user in the Word doc to later be included in the email.
[image]

What I have so far (the remaining parts are irrelevant to this question):

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strData As String
Dim ola As New Outlook.Application
Dim maiMessage As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fs

myfilename = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0)
 
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oItem.Display

With oItem
    .CC = "Houston@state.com"
    .Subject = "Quote No: " & myfilename
End With
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

Comment: Isn't better to use [Mail Merge](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-use-mail-merge-in-microsoft-word/) in Word?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. But you can use your own placeholders in the message body (see `HTMLBody`) of your template. When a message is created based on the template you can replace such placeholders by replacing custom tags with your own data.

---

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.